# to save/overwrite machine learning model as single file in spark cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I have machine learning model using LinearRegression. I have spark clusters of 5 vm. After training the model, I want to save the model so I can use it afterwards simply loading into memory.

I have tried using

```
model.save("/tmp/model.pkl").
```

When saved like this, it creates the directory named model.pkl in all nodes of the clusters which has file as `data/, metadata/, _SUCCESS, ._SUCCESS.crc, _temporary, .. and some more`

Is there a way to save the model as single file like `model.pkl`?

Also when I retrain the model using newly available data, I am using `model.write().overwrite().save("/tmp/model.pkl")` to overwrite the existing models, so new updated model be persisted in filesystem.

But then I get exception as `FileAlreadyExistsException`

```
An error occurred while calling o94.save.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/tmp/cat_model.pkl/metadata already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:131)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1070)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1035)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1035)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1035)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:961)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:961)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:961)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:960)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1489)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1468)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1468)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1468)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsWriter$.saveMetadata(ReadWrite.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel$LinearRegressionModelWriter.saveImpl(LinearRegression.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWriter.save(ReadWrite.scala:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I overwrite the existing model?

I have write permission for directory `/tmp` on all nodes of the cluster.

When trying to load the model using `model.load('/tmp/model.pkl')`,
I am getting error as

```
An error occurred while calling o94.load.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection
```

It seems, `save(path)` did not saved model correctly.
How can I load the saved model correctly.
What would be right way to save and again load the learning model in spark?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Use distributed file system where working with cluster.

> Is there a way to save the model as single file like model.pkl?

It is not. Different files in the output relate to different components of the model.

> Also when I retrain the model using newly available data, I am using model.write().overwrite().save("/tmp/model.pkl") to overwrite the existing models, so new updated model be persisted in filesystem (...) then I get exception as FileAlreadyExistsException

In general you shouldn't use local files system for writes on the cluster. While write might partially succeed (note that `_temporary` directory is not correctly removed as it would be with a distributed file system) it is not possible to load back data in that case, because executors will see inconsistent state of the filesystem.